# Trying to use jquery and jquery-ujs with Browserify but getting Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ecmascript-6, browserify

I'm working on a ruby on rails project and am using Browserify to manage javascript dependencies etc. However, when I run the application I keep getting a "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined" because jquery-ujs tries to call jQuery but it's not available. I know jQuery is being loaded on page because when I include the code below without `import 'jquery-ujs'` I am able to successfully use jQuery by calling both $ and jQuery. However, I can't seem to be able to also include 'jquery-ujs'.

```
import 'jquery';
import $ from 'jquery';
global.jQuery  = $;
import 'jquery-ujs'
```

And here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "watchify": "watchify -vd -p browserify-hmr -e frontend/application.js -o app/assets/javascripts/application.js",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production browserify frontend/application.js | uglifyjs -c warnings=false -m > app/assets/javascripts/application.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jquery-ujs": "^1.2.2",
    "vue": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-resource": "^0.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.0.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "browserify": "^12.0.1",
    "browserify-hmr": "^0.3.1",
    "browserify-shim": "^3.8.12",
    "cross-env": "^1.0.6",
    "uglify-js": "^2.5.0",
    "vue-hot-reload-api": "^1.2.2",
    "vueify": "^8.0.0",
    "vueify-insert-css": "^1.0.0",
    "watchify": "^3.4.0"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify",
      "babelify",
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is written in my application.js file along with a lot of other stuff which is generated with browserify:

```
var _jquery = require('jquery');
var _jquery2 = _interopRequireDefault(_jquery);
require('jquery-ujs');
```

Comment: Can you show your application.js

Comment: @luissimo the application.js file is generated with browserify so it is extremely long 10,000+ lines so I don't think its feasible to post the whole thing on here. Is there something specific you're looking for?

Comment: Yeah just the require part  '//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs' etc

Comment: @luissimo added the require parts but as I am using browserify and not sprockets it's not in the same format as what you wrote

Comment: Oh oke , in your application.html.erb try including the jquery script before all other scripts.

Comment: @luissimo adding it directly to application.html.erb does indeed work as expected but doing it that way kind of defeats the purpose of using browserify in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work by adding these lines. I'm not sure why you have to use require instead of import in this case...

```
import $ from 'jquery';
global.jQuery = $
require('jquery-ujs')
```